# How to select color of a specific pixel in Rails?

Tags: ruby

**Is it possible to somehow do the following in rails?**

1. Get the color of a specific pixel from a image (for example at location 10px by 10px)
2. Delete all occurrences of that color from the image (gets replaced with transparent pixels)
3. Crop image to exclude any outer transparent pixels

Any advise would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rails? No.

Ruby? Yes.

Check out RMagick: http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code of how I did it using RMagick (thanks Alex Wayne for pointing me to RMagick)...

```
    require 'RMagick'
    img = Magick::Image.read("sample.jpg").first
    bgcolor = img.pixel_color(1,1)
    img.format = "PNG"
    img.fuzz = 0.05
    img.trim!
    img.resize_to_fit!(100, 40)

    bg = Magick::Image.new(100,40) { self.background_color = bgcolor }
    img = bg.composite(img, Magick::CenterGravity, Magick::OverCompositeOp)

    img.write("modified.png")
```

For my initial requirement (to just remove the outer colors or blank borders), the following is all you need:

```
require 'RMagick'
img = Magick::Image.read("sample.jpg").first
img.trim!
img.write("sample.jpg")
```